# EDIT FOOTER IN ELEGANT MAGAZINE THEME

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I have a free version of WordPress Elegant Magazine theme. In footer, with copyrights, the name of the theme is mentioned; not editable through visual customisation.

I tried to edit theme code but was getting error msgs.

What should i do now? Would you help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

In the Customized option, You can give `display:none` on the **Addition CSS** area for footer copyrights class name. Then give your own copyrights text through the footer widgets

OR

Just find the copyrights text on the wordpress/wp-content/themes/elegant/ folder and change it

It will work on...

Comment: I wrote this same thing in additional css.. uplon publishing everything was as it was before

Answer (score 0):

Create child theme. Read how to create child theme https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ or download the child theme i have made https://github.com/snuffybg/Elegant-Magazine-Child-theme.git

In your child theme you will find footer.php file where at line 144 to 147 code is edited. You need child theme in case the theme have updates and to avoid overwrite files.

Update: After download go to Wordpress dashboard -> Appearance -> Themes . Add new and upload elegant-magazine-child.zip after that activate.

Comment: Sir i ve downldd ur github code. Kindly Guide me what's next

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sir, I have done the same. But upon activating, the complete look of the parent theme was lost. I had to re-activate the parent theme.

Comment: I have updated the zip. Could you try again ?

Comment: The issue is resolved, sir. I was successful in making changes to the source code finally. I thank you so much!